# Как написать бота для игры Avicii Gravity HD на Python?

Tags: python, бот

Всем привет!
Недавно увидел статью про Python про написание бота для онлайн игры
[Как написать игрового бота на Python для Web](https://mad-dog.ru/how-to-build-python-bot-web-games/<br><br)

И на основе полученной информации захотел написать собственного бота для игры Avicii Gravity HD

[image: Avicii Gravity HD]

Механика игры довольно проста. Смотрим какая фигурка не нанесет нам урона, пролетаем через неё
Но проблема в том что я не могу придумать как это реализовать, то есть как 'сказать' боту что-то типа "Запомни фигурку, и если ты не находишься на одной линии с ней ищи её и 'беги' туда". 
С вопросом выделить фигурку думаю ещё справлюсь, но как в динамической игре бот  увидит куда ему лететь ?

Comment: Можно спросить, а какой ответ вы ожидаете получить?

Comment: Я вроде все разжевал в вопросе, но ладно если трудно понять уточню. Если перейти по ссылке можно обнаружить что бот написан при помощи PIL. И в вопросе было сказано 'на основе полученной информации'. Соединяем и получаем умное умозаключение. Как при помощи PIL сказать боту "Тебе нужна определённая фигурка, только она не причинит тебе вреда". Ну точнее просто не куда

Comment: "И на основе полученной информации захотел написать собственного бота" - ну так пишите, в чем вопрос то? Вы начните, столкнетесь с проблемой, сформулируйте вопрос, выложите его сюда, люди подскажут. А вопрос "Как написать бота?" - подразумевает только один ответ - руками.